# Pandas str split. Can I skip line which gives troubles?

Tags: dataframe, split, line, skip

I have a dataframe (all5) including one column with dates('CREATIE_DATUM'). Sometimes the notation is 01/JAN/2015 sometimes it's written as 01-JAN-15.
I only need the year, so I wrote the following code line:

`all5[['Day','Month','Year']]=all5['CREATIE_DATUM'].str.split('-/',expand=True)`

but I get the following error:

`columns must be same length as key`

so I assume somewhere in my dataframe (>100.000 lines) a value has more than two '/' signs.
How can I make my code skip this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `pd.to_datetime` and then use `.dt` property to access day, month and year:

```py
x = pd.to_datetime(all5["CREATIE_DATUM"])

all5["Day"] = x.dt.day
all5["Month"] = x.dt.month
all5["Year"] = x.dt.year
```